# Decrease a Value Given a List of Percentages

Tags: r

Suppose I have a `starting_value` of 127, and I want to slowly decrease it by successively multiplying it by various `pct`s.  How would I do that?

```r
starting_value <- 127

data.frame(
  pcts = c(0.64, 0.07, 0.44, 0.79, 0.67, 0.12, 0.58, 0.56, 0.59, 0.21)
)
#>    pcts
#> 1  0.64
#> 2  0.07
#> 3  0.44
#> 4  0.79
#> 5  0.67
#> 6  0.12
#> 7  0.58
#> 8  0.56
#> 9  0.59
#> 10 0.21
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `starting_value * cumprod(df$pcts)`? What is your desired output?

Comment: @Onyambu That was my desired output.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit: [Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76343715/decrease-a-value-given-a-list-of-percentages#comment134623563_76343715)

```
starting_value * cumprod(df$pcts)

# [1] 81.280000000  5.689600000  2.503424000  1.977704960  1.325062323
# [6]  0.159007479  0.092224338  0.051645629  0.030470921  0.006398893
```

[See the documentation for cumprod](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html).